# Javascript onclick button

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, conditional-statements

I am creating a form with HTML and javascript. I need to show a div ID depending on 2 buttons clicked on the first 2 choices - if the car year is 2019 and the car make is ACURA then show div ID for 2019 Acura models.

Here is the code - I'm really stuck on creating the function statement to check for previous buttons clicked and show the new div ID of "model". Is there a better way?

```
<form>
<h4> Auto Insurance Quote </h4> <br>
<div id= "year">
<input type= "button" id="showform" 
value="2019" name="showform" 
onclick="showhideForm(this.value);"</button>
<input type= "button" id="b2018" value="2018" 
name="showform" 
onclick="showhideForm(this.value);"</button>
<input type= "button" id="showform" 
value="2017" name="showform" 
onclick="showhideForm(this.value);"</button>
<input type= "button" id="showform" 
   value="2016" name="showform" 
onclick="showhideForm(this.value);"</button>
</div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function showhideForm(showform) {
if (showform == "2019") {

 document.getElementById("div1").style.display 
  = 
 'block';

 document.getElementById("year").style.display 
  = 
 'none';

   }

    if (showform == "2018") {

 document.getElementById("div1").style.display 
 = 'block';

  document.getElementById("year").style.display 
   = 'none';
   }

      if (showform == "2017") {

  document.getElementById("div1").style.display 
 = 'block';

  document.getElementById("year").style.display 
  = 'none';
   }
    if (showform == "2016") {

  document.getElementById("div1").style.display 
   = 'block';


 document.getElementById("year").style.display 
 = 'none';
  }
  }


     </script>

     <div id="div1" style="display:none">
    <input type= "button" id="acura" 
   value="ACURA" name="showform" 
    onclick="myFunction()"</button>
    <input type= "button" id="showform" 
    value="AUDI" name="showform" 
    onclick="showhideForm(this.value);" 
   </button>
    <input type= "button" id="showform" 
   value="BMW" name="showform" 
   onclick="showhideForm(this.value);"</button>
   <input type= "button" id="showform" 
    value="BUICK" name="showform" 
    onclick="showhideForm(this.value);" 
     </button>

    </div>

      <div id= acura_2018 style="display:none">
        <input type= "button" id="showform" 
      value="ILX BASE" name="showform" 
     onclick="showhideForm(this.value);" 
     </button>
        <input type= "button" id="showform" 
      value="ILX PREMIUM" name="showform" 
        onclick="showhideForm(this.value);" 
         </button>
      <input type= "button" id="showform" 
        value="ILX PREMIUM STYLE" 
         name="showform" 
        onclick="showhideForm(this.value);" 
        </button>
      <input type= "button" id="showform" 
      value="ILX SPECIAL EDITION" 
       name="showform" 
        onclick="showhideForm(this.value);" 
        </button>

        </div>

       <script>


       function
      var 2018 
       =document.getElementById("b2018");
         var 2018 
      =document.getElementById("ACURA");

       b2018.onclick = function() 
       }

          </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Doug. Just a few things I can think of with, your function passing the buttons value could you just store that as a variable like this:

```
strYear = showform;
//You only needs these lines once:
document.getElementById("div1").style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById("year").style.display = 'none';
```

Do the same for the model and it's function:

```
strModel = showform;
```

Then if after your the div do:

```
var divIdentified = document.getElementById(strYear + strModel);
```

Think that is what you're after. You shouldn't need all those if statements unless your planning on doing something else. Also I'd have a look at switch statements. It would make your code look tidier and more efficient when you do need to use alot of ifs.

Hope this is of some help

Comment: Just another note. Look at W3 schools if you're learning. It's a brilliant resource.